# Output the common lines (similarities) of two text files (the opposite of diff)?

Tags: command-line, shell, diff

Diff is a great tool to display the changes between two files. But how to display the similarities of two text files (while ignoring the differences)?

I.e. sample input:

```
a:
Foo Bar
X
Hello
World
42

b:
Foo Baz
Hello
World
23
```

Pseudo output (something like this):

```
@@ 2,3
=Hello World
```

Just sorting both files and using comm is not enough, because in that case the line information is lost.

Comment: You desire to _throw away_ linewise information...by placing the output on one line? Assuming one-to-four words per line, that means you lose understand whether `Hello World Mars Venus` in your output originated on one line--or up to 4 different lines.

Comment: And what about duplicates? If `Hello` appears identically on four duplicated lines in each input file, do you want `Hello` to appear four times in your output?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about using diff, even though you don't want a diff?  Try this:

```
diff --unchanged-group-format='@@ %dn,%df 
  %<' --old-group-format='' --new-group-format='' \
  --changed-group-format='' a.txt b.txt
```

Here is what I get with your sample data:

```
$ cat a.txt 
Foo Bar
X
Hello
World
42
$ cat b.txt 
Foo Baz
Hello
World
23
$ diff --unchanged-group-format='@@ %dn,%df
%<' --old-group-format='' --new-group-format='' \
  --changed-group-format='' a.txt b.txt
@@ 2,3
Hello
World
```

Comment: You can avoid embedding a literal newline like this: `...%df'$'\n''%<'...`

Comment: You can also do it like this: `... --unchanged-group-format="@@ %dn,%df%c'\012'%<" ...` (Note the double quotes.)

Comment: Great stuff! I did not know these options, because I just looked at the diff man page ...

Comment: I'm using 
diff --version
diff (GNU diffutils) 2.8.1
And I get the following error:
diff: conflicting output style options
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.

Comment: I was getting "error: diff: conflicting output style options diff" because I had a diff alias defined. Use `which diff` to see if this is your problem.

Answer (score 37):

```
grep -Fxf file1 file2
```

`-F` means match plain strings (not regexps), `-x` means only whole-line matches, `-f` means take 'patterns' (i.e. lines) from the file named as its argument

Comment: This is not worked for me.

Comment: @ChamindaBandara I’ve tried it with both the Mac’s built-in (POSIX/BSD) grep, where it fails, and with GNU grep, where it works as advertised. People tend to forget that the two are different.

Comment: @ajgringo and frungi [standard grep](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) accepts the given options, which means the suggested edit which proposed a "GNU grep" qualification would have made this answer worse rather than better.

Answer (score 13):

`comm` can be used. `man comm` for all the options but you'll want to use `comm -12 ...` to show only lines that exist in both inputs.

As people have pointed out, you need to pass your input through `sort` first.

Comment: Hm, that works only for common lines that are at the same line number in both files.

Comment: comm seems to be for sorted files only and not to give that useful output for the usecase of the OP. His example:
$ comm -12 a b 
Hello
World
comm: file 1 is not in sorted order
comm: file 2 is not in sorted order

Comment: @maxschlepzig: you should sort your files before passing them to comm.

Comment: By sorting you get rid of all information on the position of the common lines, though. You wouldn't sort files before comparing them with diff, either.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there is a single command that does what you want it to do. You can try to combine the output of `diff` with `grep`, though. If your text files contain none of the characters `|`,`<`,`>`, the following gives you somewhat useful output:

```
$ diff --side-by-side a b | grep -n -v "[|<>]"
3:Hello                             Hello
4:World                             World
```

Comment: Try this: `diff --width=155 --left-column --side-by-side a b | grep -n -v '|' | sed 's/ *($//'`

Comment: that looks better -- but you have to include < and > in the grep to get also rid of added lines in either file.

Comment: +1 For a simple, visual, and self-explanatory solution.

Answer (score 5):

Dick Grune wrote a family of tools for this kind of thing:

http://dickgrune.com/Programs/similarity_tester/

There are versions that parse the syntax of various languages, so that things like renamed variables can be seen as unchanged.

It is packaged as `similarity-tester` in Debian and Ubuntu.